# How to share dependencies with local modules in Node.js?

Tags: node.js

I'm working on a simple CLI Node.js app for processing files.

App structure:

```
- app.js
- recipes/recipe-one.js
- recipes/recipe-two.js
```

Each file in /recipes folder is a function that is responsible for processing an input file. The problem that I'm facing is related to sharing dependencies.

All recipes share the same dependencies, however, I cannot wrap my head around setting those in the app.js

Whenever I do:

```
// app.js
const fs = require('fs');
const Recipe = require('recipes/recipe-one')
```

and Recipe relies on `fs` - I'm getting an error saying that fs is not defined.

**Question**: How can I have dependencies specified in one place then? What I'm missing?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you stick to the traditional approach of importing required modules in individual files. Still this is the possible workaround you can do to make it work.

You can use **global** keyword to define the modules you wanna use in multiple files. Code in 'app.js' will be:

```
const fs = require('fs');
global.fs = fs;
```

and somewhere in project you can use it like

```
global.fs.readFileSync() {...}
```

without importing/requiring it. You can read more about global [here](https://stackabuse.com/using-global-variables-in-node-js/).

Hope this helps :)